# C# Iterating char array very slow

Tags: c#, java, arrays

I am calculating a hash of a text string in Java and C#, requirement being that if the text strings are identical the hash is the same.
I settled on Java's .hashValue() as it is quite simple and straight forward(and I am fault tolerant to a potential collision), - or so I thought.
My C# implementation turns out to be unbearably slow.

Here is the implementation in c# (java is almost identical) :

```
        char[] val = string.ToCharArray();
        int hash = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < string.Count(); i++) {
            hash = 31 * hash + val[i];
        }
```

Now I pass in two text strings, both read from text files on disc (C#, System.IO.File.ReadAllText), the fist is 10kb the second is 100kb

java zips right by both of them and generates the result. C# takes about 600ms for the 10kb file and then a whooping 50 seconds for the latter. 
In essense, the C# version does not scale linearly, and at a certain size it becomes a not-feasible approach.
Given the exponential scaling, and that i cant fanthom ADD and MUL begins to take more time, it leads me to believe it has to be some memory management that goes haywire with C# indexing the char array.
Is this expected behavior ... or what am I missing? :-)

Best regards.

Comment: Have you tried using `val.Length` since the count method might actually by counting the string each time?

Comment: Is "string" even legal as a variable name?

Comment: @ShellShock No, it is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.Count(); i++) {
```

In this line, you should either use `string.Length` (no parentheses) or, preferably, `val.Length`.

`Count()` is an extension method which gets the length of the string by enumerating it every time you call it.

A more conventional C# implementation of the same algorithm would be:

```
int hash = 0;
foreach(char c in string)
{
    hash = 31 * hash + c;
}
```

As pointed out in the comments, `string` is not a valid variable name is C# since it is a keyword (an alias for `System.String`), but I kept it here for clarity.

Comment: Indeed - using Count() it became an O(N^2) operation!

Comment: Thanks alot, this is it :) .. Consider me wiser.
"string" was substituted in my original question, i thought it was transparent.

Comment: I wasnt going to, but apparantly I am, since I am here typing now...so here goes ... If String/string is immutable.. why would .Count have to 'count' the length each time? Seems unnecessarily inefficient?

Comment: It _is_ unnecessarily ineffecient, that's why you should use `String.Length` instead, which is just a property of a string. The `.Count()' extension method is defined on any type that implements `IEnumerable' (similar to `Iterable' in Java) to get the length of a sequence, _without knowing anything particular about the sequence_. `String` implements `IEnumerable` because it's essentially a sequence of chars, so you can use the `Count()` method, but it has no idea what kind of sequence `String` actually is, so the only way to determine the sequence's length is to enumerate it until it stops.

Comment: Okay, I got that, what I am asking is, would it not be safe to override .Count in string/String and just return length? .. Not trying to cover or justify my original bad-form-code, just curious :)

Comment: Good question. In fact, `.Count()` is not a method of the `String` class, but instead an "extension method" defined on the `IEnumerable` interface. Extension methods in C# are a bit of syntactic sugar where you can call a method that is defined as `static int Count(this IEnumerable arg)` as if it were an instance method. You can now do `myString.Count()` and the compiler translates it to `Enumerable.Count(myString)`. So this method would than have to check if its argument was a string in order to call `Length`. It actually does this check to see if it's an ICollection, but not for string.